# What is the most cross-browser way to render an SVG shape in an arbitrary color?

Tags: css, svg

Given just a flat, 100% black, 2D SVG shape, how can I render this in an arbitrary color, as cross-browser as possible?

Answer (score 2):

- Raphael (http://raphaeljs.com/), works in IE5+ (fallback via VML), Safari, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, but not in Android before Honeycomb.
- Svgweb (http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) works in all, but has fallback via Flash (not supported in IPad, IPhone).
- Canvg (http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) works in all those that support SVG or Canvas.

I would say Raphael is your best bet.

Rendering a 2D in color in Raphael is easy. For example:

```
<script type="javascript">
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
// Creates a red-filled cross-looking shape
paper.path("M10,10L50,50M50,10L10,50").attr({stroke: "red", fill:"red"});
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, you didn’t address the part about rendering the image in an arbitrary color. Is it straightforward using the above toolkits?

Comment: @AlanH SVG is all about filling things with color. If you have access to the source SVG, you can change its fill (using DOM methods). Any browser that supports SVG supports this.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a sample on how to do it with Raphael. Hope that helps.